# TFS 2017 - BuildAgent in Queue is ignored

Tags: tfs, build-agent

I have two BuildAgents in my Default queue. Both checkboxes for active are set, both are online and running and also shown as online and running. When I start a build on that queue, it is only sent to one Agent, never to the other. If I stop this one Agent, I get the error message, that there is no agent available. But there is!

Has anyone an idea, whats going on here?

Specs: I have an On-premise-TFS-2017 (it was upgraded from 2012). Build Agents where installed the way, that TFS-2017 describes it on the interface.

Comment: Please check the agent `Capabilities`, if there are no the required capabilities for the specific build on the agent, then you will get the `"no agent available"` error message. You can compare the `Capabilities` for the agents to check if there are any differentences between them.

Answer (score 0):

You get the message means that the build agent `Capabilities` don't meet the conditions which set in build definition (**Demands** settings) or build requirements.

Please try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Check the **Demands** in your build definition, make sure the demands
  you added are existing on build agent `Capabilities`. If not existing
  there, just try to **Add Capability** for the agent manually.
- Somethings the agent cannot automatically identify some components as
  the system Capabilities. In this case you can try comparing the
  `Capabilities` between the two build agents to identify the
  differents. **Add the missed Capability for the failed agent** manually.
  Then try it again.
- Deploy a new agent to check that.

Reference this article : [TFS/VSTS Build – System Capabilities and Demands](https://www.marcusfelling.com/blog/2017/tfsvsts-build-system-capabilities-demands/)

[image]